# Python SQLite3 UPDATE with tuple only uses last value

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to update all rows of 1 column of my database with a big tuple.

```
c.execute("SELECT framenum FROM learnAlg")
db_framenum = c.fetchall()
print(db_framenum)

db_framenum_new = []
# How much v6 framenum differentiates from v4
change_fn = 0
for f in db_framenum:
    t = f[0]
    if t in change_numbers:
        change_fn += 1
    t = t + change_fn
    db_framenum_new.append((t,))

print("")
print(db_framenum_new)
c.executemany("UPDATE learnAlg SET framenum=?", (db_framenum_new))
```

First I take the existing values of the column 'framenum', which look like:

```
[(0,), (1,), (2,) , ..., (104,)]
```

Then I transform the tuple to a list so I can change some values in the `for f in db_framenum:` loop, which result in a similar tuple:

```
[(0,), (1,), (2,) , ..., (108,)]
```

### Problem

So far so good, but then I try to update the column 'framenum' with these new framenumbers:

```
c.executemany("UPDATE learnAlg SET framenum=?", (db_framenum_new))
```

I expect the rows in the column 'framenum' to have the new values, but instead they all have the value: **108** (which is the last value of the tuple 'db_framenum_new'). Why are they not being updated in order (from 1 till 108)?

Expect:

```
framenum: 1, 2, .., 108
```

Got:

```
framenum: 108, 108, ..., 108
```

- **Note:** The list of tuples has not become longer, only certain values have been changed to. Everything above 46 has +1, everything above 54 additional +1 (+2 total)...
- **Note2:** The column is created with: 'framenum INTEGER'. Another column has the PRIMARY KEY if this matters, made with: 'framekanji TEXT PRIMARY KEY', which has (for now) all value 'NULL'.

## Edit

Solved my problem, but I'm still interested in proper use of c.executemany(). I don't know why this only updates the first rowid:

```
c.execute("SELECT rowid, framenum FROM learnAlg")
db_framenum = c.fetchall()
print(db_framenum)

db_framenum_new = []
# How much v6 framenum differentiates from v4
change_fn = 0
for e, f in enumerate(db_framenum):
    e += 1
    t = f[1]
    if t in change_numbers:
        change_fn += 1
        t = t + change_fn
        db_framenum_new.append((e,t))

    print(db_framenum_new)
    c.executemany("UPDATE learnAlg SET framenum=? WHERE rowid=?",
                   (db_framenum_new[1], db_framenum_new[0]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are telling the database to update **all** rows with the same `framenum`. That's because the `UPDATE` statement did not select any specific row. You need to tell the database to change one row at a time, by including a primary key for each value.

Since you are only altering specific framenumbers, you could ask the database to only provide those specific rows instead of going through all of them. You probably also need to specify an *order* in which to change the numbers; perhaps you need to do so in incrementing framenumber order?

```
c.execute("""
    SELECT rowid, framenum FROM learnAlg
    WHERE framenum in ({})
    ORDER BY framenum
    """.format(', '.join(['?'] * len(change_numbers))), 
    change_numbers)
update_cursor = conn.cursor()    
for change, (rowid, f) in enumerate(c, 1):
    update_cursor.execute("""
        UPDATE learnAlg SET framenum=? WHERE rowid=?""",
        (f + change, rowid))
```

I altered the structure somewhat there; the query limits the results to frame numbers in the `change_numbers` sequence only, through a `WHERE IN` clause. I loop over the cursor directly (no need to fetch all results at once) and use separate `UPDATE`s to set the new frame number. Instead of a manual counter I used `enumerate()` to keep count for me.

If you needed to *group* the updates by `change_numbers`, then just tell the database to do those updates:

```
change = len(change_numbers)
for framenumber in reversed(change_numbers):
    update_cursor.execute("""
        UPDATE learnAlg SET framenum=framenum + ? WHERE framenum=?
        """, (change, framenumber))
    change -= 1
```

This starts at the *highest* framenumber to avoid updating framenumbers you already updated before. This does assume your `change_numbers` are sorted in incremental order.

Your `executemany` update should just pass in the whole list, not just the first two items; you do need to alter how you append the values:

```
for e, f in enumerate(db_framenum):
# ...
    db_framenum_new.append((t, e))  # framenum first, then rowid


c.executemany("UPDATE learnAlg SET framenum=? WHERE rowid=?",
               db_framenum_new)
```

Note that the `executemany()` call takes place *outside* the `for` loop!

Comment: Thanks for the rowid and sorry I misinformed you. Everything >= 46 needed +1, everything >= 54 + 2, ... those numbers are in change_numbers)

Comment: @NumesSanguis: then why not have the database do that instead?

Comment: @NumesSanguis: added an alternative approach that updates the `framenum` based on the `change_numbers` list; no need to select first, just have SQLite worry about what rows match.

Comment: thank you for your quick responses! The c.executemany now works :) It seems that the 2nd block of code is optimal, but not only e.g. 46 needs +1, also 47+1 and 54+2, 55+2, .... Is there an easy way to include in the sqlite3 code the use of MAX()row and walk back, or should I make an extra SELECT MAX() statement so I can use that for a loop?

Comment: @NumesSanguis: I'm sure you can work out some kind of business rules here. :-)

Comment: I would do c.execute("SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM learnAlg"), max = c.fetchone()[0] and make a loop of this, but then I still need 2 sqlite statements. Is there a way to do it in 1 or is this already optimal?

Comment: @NumesSanguis: not sure what you are trying to achieve with that, actually. Perhaps that's something for a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Martijn Pieters, using rowid is what I needed. This is the code that made it work for me:

```
c.execute("SELECT rowid, framenum FROM learnAlg")
db_framenum = c.fetchall()
print(db_framenum)

# How much v6 framenum differentiates from v4
change_fn = 0
for e, f in enumerate(db_framenum):
    e += 1
    db_framenum_new = f[1]
    if db_framenum_new in change_numbers:
        change_fn += 1
    db_framenum_new = db_framenum_new + change_fn

    c.execute("UPDATE learnAlg SET framenum=? WHERE rowid=?",
              (db_framenum_new, e))
```

However I still don't know how to properly use c.executemany(). See edit for updated question.

Comment: There isn't really a need to post your final solution if the answer pointed to the right solution. I've addressed your executemany issue.